# GTK ScrolledWindow max_content_width/height does not work with TextView

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm creating a simple "sticky note" application using GTK3. I implement the notes by wrapping a `TextView` in `ScrolledWindow`. I put them in `Layout`, so they are free to grow. I set `min`/`max_content_width`/`height` to control note size: I want it to start with some minimum size, then grow up to some point as text is entered into `TextView` and then once max size is reached, I want scrollbars to appear.

Minimum size works as expected, however `ScolledWindow` never grows - as soon as entered text stops fitting the initial area scrollbars appear. I tried setting `vexpand`/`hexpand` on both `ScrolledWindow` and `TextView`, but it didn't help.

There is little documentation on this, but as I understand it, `max_content_width`/`height` should do exactly what I need: expand `ScrolledWindow` up to some size, then show scrollbars. Is it some bug or am I missing something?

I'm using Rust, GTK 3.24.24 on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying this, I think it should work to get the actual size of the Textview and setting it to the `width request / height request` of the ScrolledWindow, unless it is more than your max size. Probably by connecting to the TextView size changed signal.

To tell you the truth, I am not sure what `max_content_width/height` does in practical life.

Comment: I already tried what you suggest, but there is another issue that I believe is a bug. When I resize ScrolledWindow manually based on size reported by TextView, sometimes it's not enough and causes scrollbar to appear. The same thing happens, when scroll policy is set to NEVER, SrolledWindow resizes automatically then, but sometimes to little to accomodate the TextView. I reported my findings here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/3515